# Finding roots of polynomial $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, where $p$ is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I am not quite sure how to approach such a problem. In particular, I am wondering how to find the roots of the following polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_p = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$:

> $f(x) = x^{2p^2}- \overline{2}x^{p^2} - x^p + \overline{2} \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.

Any explanation or advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: If $p = 2$, then $f = x^8-x^2 = x^2(x^6-1) = x^2((x^3)^2-1) = x^2(x^3-1)^2$. This is because $a^p +b^p = (a+b)^p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. So the roots are $0$ and powers of a primitive third root of unity $\xi \in \overline{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}$

Comment: A starting point is Fermat's Little Theorem, to the effect that $x^p \equiv x \bmod p$.  Use that to simplify the equation modulo $p$ that $f(x) \equiv 0 \bmod p$.

Comment: The title suggests you want *roots* in $\mathbb Z_p$, and I'm assuming you mean the integers modulo $p$.  The body of the Question should echo and probably amplify that this is the problem.  Note that the same notation $\mathbb Z_p$  is used by many authors to mean $p$-adic integers, which poses quite a different problem.

Comment: I still don't understand whether you want to find the roots (in some algebraic closure) of a polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb F_p$ or if you want to find the roots in $\Bbb  F_p$ of a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! I am confused by this problem as well... I think it may have been badly phrased and the latter is the case... what do you mean by finding the roots in some algebraic closure? Many thanks

Comment: If you haven't seen that term yet, then don't worry about it. My point is that, for example, when $p = 2$ we have $x^2(x^3-1)^2$. The polynomial $x^3-1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb F_2$, but we can split it in a larger field that contains $\Bbb F_2$ to compute "all" the roots (although the latter will not be elements of $\Bbb F_2$ itself)

Comment: oops, there's an obvious mistake in my last comment: the polynomial $x^3-1$ is reducible, as $1$ is a root. I meant that $x^3-1  = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ with the latter irreducible in $\Bbb F_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^p \equiv x \bmod p \Rightarrow x^{2p^2}=(x^p)^{2p} \equiv x^{2p} \equiv x^2 \bmod{p}$

$x^p \equiv x \bmod p \Rightarrow x^{p^2} \equiv x \bmod p$

$x^{2p^2}- \overline{2}x^{p^2} - x^p + \overline{2} = x^2 -3x+2=(x-2)(x-1)=0$

$x \equiv 2$ or $x \equiv 1$